# python print and whitespace

Tags: python

I am trying to print a result for example:

```
for record in result:
    print varone,vartwo,varthree
```

I am trying to concatenate the variables which are from an SQL query, but I am getting whitespace. How can I strip whitespace from a 'print'? Should I feed the result into a variable then do a 'strip(newvar)' then print the 'newvar'?

Comment: Where are you getting whitespace? Please show what output you are getting, and what output you expect.

Comment: Also, your code is unclear. Where are `varone` etc. comming from and what type are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
print "%s%s%s" % (varone,vartwo,varthree)
```

will replace the first `%s` in the quotes with the value in `varone`, the second `%s` with the contents of `vartwo`, etc.

**EDIT**:
As of Python 2.6 you should prefer this method:

```
print "{0}{1}{2}".format(varone,vartwo,varthree)
```

(Thanks Space_C0wb0y)

Comment: You should prefer using [`string.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: If you expect the variables to be unpacked from a `record`, you can also write `"{0}{1}{2}".format(*record)`

Answer (score 1):

print put whitespace between variables and emit a newline. If this is just the whistespaces between strings that bother you, just concatenate the strings before printing.

```
print varone+vartwo+varthree
```

Really, there is (much) more than one way to do it. It always comes out creating a new string combining your values before printing it. Below are the various ways I can think of:

```
# string concatenation
# the drawback is that your objects are not string
# plus may have another meaning
"one"+"two"+"three"

#safer, but non pythonic and stupid for plain strings
str("one")+str("two")+str("three")

# same idea but safer and more elegant
''.join(["one", "two", "three"])

# new string formatting method
"{0}{1}{2}".format("one", "two", "three")

# old string formating method
"%s%s%s" % ("one", "two", "three")

# old string formatting method, dictionnary based variant
"%(a)s%(b)s%(c)s" % {'a': "one", 'b': "two", 'c':"three"}
```

You can also avoid creating intermediate concatenated strings completely and use write instead of print.

```
import sys
for x in ["on", "two", "three"]:
    sys.stdout.write(x)
```

And in python 3.x you could also customize the print separator:

```
print("one", "two", "three", sep="")
```

Comment: Same as the others, you should use [string.format](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). Also, does noone else wonder where `varone` etc. come from? The code does not make sense.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: string.format is nice and you should write an answer using it instead of commenting everyone about it. It must be my perl background but I still belive **There Is More Than One Way To Do It**. Pure Python guys seems to believe **There Is Only The One True Way (and it is written in divine PEPs)**, that is probably the most annoying thing about them. Also varone, etc. come from the OP he probably knwow what they are. But ok, I will remove the useless `for record` part from my answer.

Comment: @kriss: The reason I posted no answer is that there are open questions the OP has not answered yet. Every answer to this question is guesswork, as the OP has not specified *what his problem actually is*. Also, I too believe that there is more than one way, but in that case there is good reasoning behind sticking to **The Way**, because it makes code compatible with future versions of Python.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Oh, no! Don't say me Guido want to remove string contatenation ? ;-)

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: more seriously, here at work I work on appliances based on an old Debian linux, and we are still stuck with python 2.4. Future is nice, but sometimes you also have to know what worked in previous versions of a language and still work in the current one). We should just say it.

Comment: Thank you for the varied answer, I have made notes

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for record in result:
    print ''.join([varone,vartwo,varthree])
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'` - try it the other way: `''.join([varone, vartwo, varthree])`

Comment: Thanks eumiro, was sleeping when I wrote it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use string formatting before you pass the string to the print command:

```
for record in result:
    print '%d%d%d' % (varone, vartwo, varthree)
```

Read about Python string formatting [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: Read about the *new* Python string formatting [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).